# Salesforce as identity provider for third party applications -How to extend it for communities

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, customer-community-plus

I have enabled Single sign on between salesforce and a thirdparty app using SAML. 
I have created a connected app where I have configured the SAML Service Provider Settings.

We am accessing the thirdparty application as a webtab in salesforce and Authentication  is working fine. users are displayed there relevant data in the webtab.

My questions is I want to access the URL of this third party application in customer community. what additional SSO configurations are needed to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create two connected apps one for the Salesforce console and one for the community

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any aditional configuration. SSO via connected apps is setup for all communities. Just make sure you get the URLs for the specific community

[image: Community SAML Configuration]

Note: the redacted part is just to protect identity of the client

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I can see my community url in the connected app.  Do I need to use these urls for some additional configurations to access the external web app in communities.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the Community URL but it is still working only for internal users and it is asking for credentials for external users who has access to community. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/203324)